# Городец-Радилов, каковы версии названия Радилов?

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Городец-Радилов на Волге основан в 12 веке. Ра - могло означать пограничное положение, как-то быть связано с древним названием Волги, радостью по поводу нового рубежа. Хотелось бы услышать обоснования версий.

Answer (score 1):

> Уточнение названия Городец на Волге притяжательным прилагательным
> Радилов (от собственного личного имени Радило или Радила), вероятно,
> указывает на воеводу, наместника или иное доверенное лицо Юрия
> Долгорукого. Распространенное мнение, будто Радилов в составе Городец
> Радилов образовано от древнего названия Волги (Ра), несостоятельно.
> Во- первых, Ра не славянское имя и возникло, как и мордовское
> обозначение Волги Раво, Рава или Рае, из индоиранского первоисточника.
>
> Ср.: древнеиндийское срава 'течение', древнеиндийское же раса и
> древнеиранское ранха — собственное название большой реки на степной
> причерноморско-прикаспий- ской прародине ариев (предков индоиранских
> народов). Во-вторых, ни из Ра, ни из Раво, Рава или Рае (если
> допустить, что их восприняли и когда-то использовали восточные
> славяне) невозможно вывести притяжательное прилагательное Радилов. Оно
> — явно из собственного личного имени Радило, Радила или Радия (с
> корнем рад-, как в словах радость или радеть).

http://www.bibliotekar.ru/2-9-4-onomastika/17.htm

Answer (score 0):

Вы русско слово "радеть" знаете? Какое еще "Ра"? Русское же название, а вы про каких-то египтян с татарами...
Скорее всего - по имени собственному. От фамилии Радилов или прозвища Радило - тот кто радеет.

Нет, посмотрел, городок-о древний, Москве ровесник. Фамилии тогда не в ходу были, значит по прозвищу.

Comment: Всё так просто у Вас получается....Скорее всего - это Ваша личная гипотеза? Или есть всё же ссылка на источник?